# FSEvents and copying large files

Tags: macos, filesystems, fsevents

I'm using FSEvents to monitor a directory of files that will have some large files copied into it. Currently FSEvents seems to be sending out a notification when I've begun copying the file, and again when it's finished copying the file. When it's a smaller file though, I only get the one event. Is there any way to check if a file is in the middle of being copied?

This is for Snow Leopard by the way.

Comment: This question relates to another question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9139445/how-to-determine-if-a-file-copy-is-completed-using-cocoa/40957388#40957388

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up just using lsof to check if the file is open at a kernel level. I only begin processing the file once lsof has determined that the file is no longer in use.

Comment: this seems not to work in a sandboxed application... `lsof: can't get PID byte count: Operation not permitted`