# How to determine if a file copy is completed using cocoa

Tags: objective-c, macos, file, fsevents

I am developing folder watcher application for MAC in XCode using Foundation framework and FSEvents API. I need to know whether the file has been completely copied to the destination before I open the file for other operation. Is there any way of knowing it? please advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From simply studying the [FSEvents API](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/ipad/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/FSEvents_Ref/FSEvents_h/) I would say that what you want is not possible. I could be mistaken, though, I have never used FSEvents myself. The asker of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4708315/fsevents-and-copying-large-files) has solved the problem by separately monitoring the new file with `lsof`.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that FSEvents API sends "create" event at beginning and "create-and-modify" at the end.  On my project I used FSEventsStream with zero latency, and "NoDefer" flag on creation.  Watching for "Modify" only events may give you information that file copy is completed.

Comment: Using "lsof" will give you no sense, because different processes may open and close the file in undefined order. In addition you will ned to filter those processes names.

Comment: "Finder" may take the file opened for a long time after copy finished.

Answer (score 0):

you can check that whether the file you want to open is exist or not?
and act accordingly.